# Create a Shopify Page that Redirects to Mailto

Tags: server, shopify, mailto, shopify-app, shopify-template

i'm trying to create a shopify page link that will redirects to the mailto. When the user visit the page, it will automatically run the mailto:EmailAddress

Comment: Can you share code that you have tried and is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

A [mail-to](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto) link is something like:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
```

To function to do it programmatically is:

```
<script>
    function mailto()
    {
        window.location.href = "mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello";
    }
</script>
```

To run the function automatically:

```
<body onload="javascript: mailto();">
```

or

```
<script>
    mailto();
</script>
```